# Can't load a column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I wanted to load a column into "y" to use it in prediction of chances in admission , it works for other columns but not "Chances of Admit" column \

This is a part of analysis.ipynb file:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

df = pd.read_csv("predict_admission.csv")
df

x = df[['GRE Score' , 'TOEFL Score' , 'SOP' , 'CGPA']]
y = df['Chance of Admit']
```

dataset link : [predict_admission](https://www.kaggle.com/prim22zz/admission)

The error i'm getting:

```
KeyError: 'Chance of Admit'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_27956/2658686205.py in <module>
      1 x = df[['GRE Score' , 'TOEFL Score' , 'SOP' , 'CGPA']]
----> 2 y = df['Chance of Admit']

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3456             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3457                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3458             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3459             if is_integer(indexer):
   3460                 indexer = [indexer]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `y=df['Chance of Admit']` to `y=df[['Chance of Admit']]`. Also check the spelling of the key.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the column by using df.rename. Worked for me.

Comment: This should be a comment, no need to add it as separate answer. you will be able to add comments after gaining some reputations on platform.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same dataset and had the same problem. The fact is that the variable name is not "Chance of Admit" but it's named "Chance of Admit " (with a blank after it). Just rename it using `dataset.rename(columns={'Chance of Admit ':'Chance of Admit'})`.